# Render Formpanel to a Tabpanel

Tags: extjs, tabpanel, formpanel

I have two .js files with different ExtJS formpanels which I reander onReady() to a DIV in the HTML file:

```
myPanel.render( 'myDiv' );
```

I would like to add/render those to a tabpanel.

Is there a easy way to do this?
And if so, how?

Thanks, Stef

Answer (score 0):

Like such ?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyTabPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.MyTabPanel',
    itemId: 'MyTabPanel',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Tab panel with the form',
            items: [myPanel] //the form panel
        }
    ]
});

//...

Ext.widget('MyTabPanel', { renderTo: 'myDiv'});
```